# How can I select multiple vertices and create faces with a single command

Tags: modeling

If I am not wrong once I saw a tutorial, in which something similar was done, but I do not remember, as it was, nor, the tutorial that was, I leave some captures to better understand what I want to do.

I hope you can to understand me and I'm sorry for my bad english.

[image]

I know I can do this by selecting the vertices and pressing the <kbd>f</kbd>

[image]

But how can I do it by selecting multiple verties and doing them all at once, with a single command.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command called [Grid Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill) which sort of does this, might be what you are looking for.

There is also an add-on included with Blender called [F2](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/F2) which (amoung other things) makes filling rows of faces easier. Have a look for some demos of how to use this on Youtube, it is a big time saver.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be what I'm looking for, but I can not make it work, maybe because of my model, this bad? I install the addons, and pulse f several times but nothing happens, can you help me with that?

Comment: Do not worry and I solve it, I was selecting it wrong after applying the first face

Comment: You saved my day F2 is very cool.

Comment: Glad to hear it :-)